# Listening Socket in Samsung Smart Tv

Tags: sockets, websocket, samsung-smart-tv, tcpsocket

I need to open a TCP socket on the Samsmung Smart TV, listening at a particular port for events from an IP camera in a local network. The camera does not have a "web server" so i cant use web sockets.

I've searched all over the net for terms like Node.js, Socket.io and I've got nothing but confused.

I stumbled on this project - [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) But i dont completely understand where and how to use it in the scenario of Samsmung Smart TV. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create listening socket on Samsung TV.

You can use Convergence API to communicate with application running on TV. See http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00027/index.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ivan. Can u pls elaborate on how I can use the convergence api in the use i mentioned in the question?

Comment: by using this api you can pass messages to tv in local network. try tutorial http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00024/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSockets since 10/28/2014: http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=d3&FileName=index.html
Compatible with SDK 4.5, 5.0, 5.1 and 2013, 2014 TV models